# How to create a new column in tsv files by combining two other columns on linux?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, awk, join

I have 70 directories that have files like below:

```
STAN002
   |______ STAN002_sasions.tsv
PTAN044
   |______ PTAN044_sasions.tsv
STAN005
   |______ STAN005_sasions.tsv
STAN050
   |______ STAN050_sasions.tsv
QRED034
   |______ QRED034_sasions.tsv
.
.
.
PREC098
   |______ PREC098_sasions.tsv
```

Each of the `.tsv` file which are in above directories have same number of columns (30 columns) and look like below in the picture:

[image]

The 1st and 2nd columns in the `.tsv` files are like below:

```
#gene1    gene2
VAV1      THAP4
ZNF75A    ZNF263
KRCC1     POLR1A
H2AFV     TANC1
B3GALT6  RP3-340N1.5
SH3BP1   CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)
PTPRO     VASN
```

Now, on linux using `awk or any bash script` I want to create a new column in all the `.tsv` files in the directories. The newly created column will be the `31st column` in the files.

It should be like combining `1st and 2nd columns` where the names are separated by `--`. The `31st column` should look like below:

```
gene1--gene2
VAV1--THAP4
ZNF75A--ZNF263
KRCC1--POLR1A
H2AFV--TANC1
B3GALT6--RP3-340N1.5
SH3BP1--CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)
PTPRO--VASN
```

I tried this way, but got wrong:

```
awk '{print $0, $1 "-" $NF}' STAN002_sasions.tsv
```

How to do that on linux in a single script on all the files? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is failing because you aren't specifying `FS` or `OFS` and you're using `$NF` instead of `$2` to identify the 2nd field (and using `"-"` when you wanted `"--"` but that's nbd).

You were close though, try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, $1 "--" $2}' STAN002_sasions.tsv
#gene1  gene2   #gene1--gene2
VAV1    THAP4   VAV1--THAP4
ZNF75A  ZNF263  ZNF75A--ZNF263
KRCC1   POLR1A  KRCC1--POLR1A
H2AFV   TANC1   H2AFV--TANC1
B3GALT6 RP3-340N1.5     B3GALT6--RP3-340N1.5
SH3BP1  CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)      SH3BP1--CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)
PTPRO   VASN    PTPRO--VASN
```

or if, as shown in your sample input/output, the first field on the first line of your input file can really start with a `#` which has to be removed when creating the new column header then:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {g=$1} NR==1{sub(/^#/,"",g)} {print $0, g "--" $2}' STAN002_sasions.tsv
#gene1  gene2   gene1--gene2
VAV1    THAP4   VAV1--THAP4
ZNF75A  ZNF263  ZNF75A--ZNF263
KRCC1   POLR1A  KRCC1--POLR1A
H2AFV   TANC1   H2AFV--TANC1
B3GALT6 RP3-340N1.5     B3GALT6--RP3-340N1.5
SH3BP1  CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)      SH3BP1--CTD-2013M15.1(192243),EMB(3603711)
PTPRO   VASN    PTPRO--VASN
```

If you have or can install GNU awk for "inplace" editing and want to update all files at once it'd be (obviously replace the string `script` with whichever of the above 2 scripts you decide to use):

```
awk -i inplace 'script' */*_sasions.tsv
```

Otherwise this will just take longer to run:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
for file in */*_sasions.tsv; do
    awk 'script' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ed Morton !

Comment: Could you please explain in detail about this `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, $1 "--" $2` Want to understand clearly so that next time I can write my own. thanq !!

Comment: Your input is tab-separated so I'm telling awk that, then I'm printing the current record with the first 2 fields appended to it. Not sure what else I can really say about that, Take a look at `BEGIN`, `FS`, `OFS`, `$0`, `$1` and `print` in the awk manual and then let me know if you have any specific questions. To learn awk get the book "Effective AWK Programming", 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins,

Comment: Small question again. Yesterday I ran on single file and it was good. Now I'm trying to run on all files and having a problem. I gave `awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, $1 "--" $2}' */*_sasions.tsv` But it didn't change anything and it gave Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options]........it showed all options. And in that I don't see `-i`

Comment: What does `awk --version` output?

Comment: GNU Awk 4.0.2 Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 .....

Comment: That's a very old (9 years old) version of gawk that predates the addition of the `-i` option. You should upgrade to the current release, 5.1.0, as you're missing a ton of useful functionality and bug fixes.

Comment: Ok I will do it. Thank you !